# Help with Bundler to figure out why it "downgraded" one of my gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, fog, gemfile

Today I checked `gem outdated` as I do periodically. Found a few that needed updating:

```
$ gem outdated
ZenTest (4.6.1 < 4.6.2)
bcrypt-ruby (2.1.4 < 3.0.0)
factory_girl (2.0.4 < 2.0.5)
fog (0.10.0 < 0.11.0)
hike (1.2.0 < 1.2.1)
net-ssh (2.1.4 < 2.2.1)
rb-fsevent (0.4.3 < 0.4.3.1)
rdoc (3.9.2 < 3.9.3)
selenium-webdriver (2.4.0 < 2.5.0)
```

So I `gem update` them and then `bundle update`. Noticed `bundle update` felt compelled to install an older version of **fog**: `Installing fog (0.9.0)`? And not sure how to figure out what's causing this dependency to be downgraded. Things were working fine under `fog 0.10.0`.

`gem dependency -R fog` says only `Carrierwave` is requiring it...and `carrierwave` hasn't changed and *was* happy with fog 0.10.0.

Any ideas? Or tools I can use to troubleshoot/understand this?

Comment: Your `Gemfile.lock` file should show a dependency hierarchy to help figure out what else might be requiring a 0.9.x version of `fog`.

Answer (score 0):

Within your gemfile and within bundler it's considered a good practice to not necessarily use the latest and newest version of a gem.

For example if there is a line in your rails gemfile such as:

gem 'globalize3', "~> 0.1.0"

... it will get the latest gem such as 0.1.2, 0.1.3 etc. but will never use 0.2.1

This is to keep backward compatibility among gem dependencies. Bundler probably follows that practice in regard to fog.